# Printing nested lists in OCaml

Tags: printf, ocaml

I am working on porting some of my Clojure code to OCaml and I was running into the following issue:

```
let rotate ll =
    let cons x y = x :: y in
    let init = List.map (fun _ -> []) (List.hd ll) in
    let rres = List.fold_right (List.map2 cons) ll init in
    List.rev rres;;

let rec spiral_print matrix acc =
    match matrix with
    | [] -> acc
    | head :: tail -> spiral_print (rotate tail)  (acc @ head);;
```

Unfortunately this leads to the following:

```
utop # spiral_print [[1; 2; 3]; [8; 9; 4]; [7; 6; 5]] [];;
Exception: (Failure hd).
```

I would like to debug why this is happening but when I turn on trace this is what I got:

```
#trace spiral_print;;
spiral_print [[1; 2; 3]; [8; 9; 4]; [7; 6; 5]] [];;
spiral_print <-- [[<poly>; <poly>; <poly>]; [<poly>; <poly>; <poly>]; [<poly>; <poly>; <poly>]]
spiral_print --> <fun>
spiral_print* <-- []
spiral_print <-- [[<poly>; <poly>]; [<poly>; <poly>]; [<poly>; <poly>]]
spiral_print --> <fun>
spiral_print* <-- [<poly>; <poly>; <poly>]
spiral_print <-- [[<poly>; <poly>]; [<poly>; <poly>]]
spiral_print --> <fun>
spiral_print* <-- [<poly>; <poly>; <poly>; <poly>; <poly>]
spiral_print <-- [[<poly>]; [<poly>]]
spiral_print --> <fun>
spiral_print* <-- [<poly>; <poly>; <poly>; <poly>; <poly>; <poly>; <poly>]
spiral_print <-- [[<poly>]]
spiral_print --> <fun>
spiral_print* <-- [<poly>; <poly>; <poly>; <poly>; <poly>; <poly>; <poly>; <poly>]
spiral_print* raises (Failure hd)
spiral_print* raises (Failure hd)
spiral_print* raises (Failure hd)
spiral_print* raises (Failure hd)
spiral_print* raises (Failure hd)
Exception: (Failure hd).
```

Is there a way to inspect the internal state of the individual function executions somehow to catch the bug?

I would use print or pretty print in other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ocamldebug` as well as toplevel will refuse to print elements of polymorphic containers, unless you constrain the types:

```
let int_spiral_print : int list list -> int list -> int list = spiral_print;;
val int_spiral_print : int list list -> int list -> int list = <fun>
# #trace int_spiral_print;;
int_spiral_print is now traced.
# int_spiral_print [[1; 2; 3]; [8; 9; 4]; [7; 6; 5]] [];;
int_spiral_print <-- [[1; 2; 3]; [8; 9; 4]; [7; 6; 5]]
int_spiral_print --> <fun>
...
```

But here having a normal backtrace would be more productive. To get it, put your code into a file, e.g,

```
$ cat spiral_print.ml

let rotate ll =
  let cons x y = x :: y in
  let init = List.map (fun _ -> []) (List.hd ll) in
  let rres = List.fold_right (List.map2 cons) ll init in
  List.rev rres

let rec spiral_print matrix acc =
  match matrix with
  | [] -> acc
  | head :: tail -> spiral_print (rotate tail)  (acc @ head)

let _ =
  Printexc.record_backtrace true;
  spiral_print [[1; 2; 3]; [8; 9; 4]; [7; 6; 5]] []
```

Notice that I added `Printexc.record_backtrace true` to enable backtrace recording that is usually disabled. You can also enable it using environment variable: `OCAMLRUNPARAM=b`. Then you can compile and run your program, to get a nice backtrace:

```
ocamlbuild spiral_print.d.byte --
Fatal error: exception Failure("hd")
Raised at file "pervasives.ml", line 30, characters 22-33
Called from file "spiral_print.ml", line 3, characters 36-48
Called from file "spiral_print.ml", line 10, characters 33-46
Called from file "spiral_print.ml", line 14, characters 2-51
```

A proper text editor (aka emacs), will even highlight for you, that the source of exception was `(List.hd ll)`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote that rotate code :-)

The function will fail if you pass it an empty list. That's your problem, I think. The giveaway is that the error comes from `List.hd`. You just need to decide what answer you want if the list is empty. Probably the answer is an empty list.

```
let rotate ll =
    if ll = [] then
        []
    else
        let cons x y = x :: y in
        let init = List.map (fun _ -> []) (List.hd ll) in
        let rres = List.fold_right (List.map2 cons) ll init in
        List.rev rres
```

Or perhaps the slightly snazzier:

```
let rotate = function
    | [] -> []
    | hd :: _ as ll -> 
        let cons x y = x :: y in
        let init = List.map (fun _ -> []) hd in
        let rres = List.fold_right (List.map2 cons) ll init in
        List.rev rres
```

But to answer your actual question, you can use [ocamldebug](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/debugger.html) to inspect values during an execution.

Comment: Yes sir you did!! I am reading your other codes in the iOS business too. Thanks for sharing, I learned a lot from you already. :)

Comment: Also the change you are suggesting here has fixed the problem.